# sum+sum equation issue in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I defined the following equation to calculate the sum of total power consumed by the system:

> TotalPower..  systemPower =e=  sum(J,P(J)) + sum(I,CP(I));

However, the variable systemPower gets only the result of the second sum and not both!. The declaration of P(J) is as following:

> P.LO(I)=0;
>
> P.up(I)=100;
>
> P.l('i1')=2;
>
> P.l('i2')=3;

Please, Can any one explain why I get the result of a single sum? How I can do to get both?. I tried also to separate them in different values but yet I get the same result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I though it is a good idea to share this it might help someone else. I used a variable directly instead of an equation and I put it in the following form and it worked.

> systemPower.l = sum(I,P.l(I))+sum(I,CP(I));